# Prototype date format validate error on OSX safari / firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, magento, prototypejs

I have the following problem on OSX 10.9.4 (Mavericks) Safari and Firefox too:

I use [bootstrap datepicker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker) for my date input

```
<label class="col-sm-3 gray required" for="received_date"><?php echo $dataHelper->__('Received Date') ?> <em>*</em></label>

<div class="col-sm-9 controls input-group date" data-date-format="<?php echo Aion_Ftc_Helper_Data::BOOTSTRAP_DATE_FORMAT ?>"  id="dp_received_date">
    <input type="text" class="required-entry custom-date validate-date" id="received_date" name="received_date">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

this is an magento site with prototype and [prototype validation](https://github.com/atetlaw/Really-Easy-Field-Validation). The valid date format is "mm-dd-yyyy" and is validating successful on windows chrome, firefox, but is get an error on osx safari and firefox (osx chrome is good too)

validate.js

```
['validate-date', 'Please enter a valid date (MM-DD-YYYY format).', function(v) {
    if(Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v)) return true;
    var regex = /^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})$/;

    if(Prototype.Browser.WebKit){
        var d = new Date(v.replace(regex, '$1-$2-$3'));
    } else {
        var d = new Date(v.replace(regex, '$3-$1-$2'));
    }
    //console.log(d);
    return (parseInt(RegExp.$2, 10) == d.getDate()) &&
        (parseInt(RegExp.$1, 10) == (1+d.getMonth()) ) &&
        (parseInt(RegExp.$3, 10) == d.getFullYear());
}],
```

what's the problem? any tips? I use jquery noconflict, too

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just simple use this:

```
['validate-date', 'Please enter a valid date (MM-DD-YYYY format).', function(v) {
    return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{4})$/.test(v);

}],
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact same issue today, do not use dashes as a seperator. This works fine in Chrome but not in Safari/iOS, replacing dashes with slashes fixes this issue. The Date function will otherwise break in Safari.

### Incorrect date string with with -

The following code will return the following

```
new Date('03-25-2017');
```

**Chrome:**

```
Sat Mar 25 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

**Safari:**

```
Invalid Date
```

So, simply replace - with /.

### Correct date string with with /

The following code will return the following

```
new Date('03/25/2017');
```

**Chrome**:

```
Sat Mar 25 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

*Safari:

```
Sat Mar 25 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```